# How do I look for string containing "." in cmd?

Tags: cmd, findstr

I am aware that "." is a wild character, yet I need to find all lines ending with a string "ey.". When I write

```
findstr /e "ey." nameofthefile.txt
```

it prints lines that end for example with "ey,", while I need only a period, no commas. Is there a way to look for strings containing periods in cmd? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /e /c:"ey."
```

`/c`: find exact string (not REGEX)

For more info, see `for /?`

Comment: thank you very much! :) it worked and I get it, so it's perfect, thanks!